# Как копировать обработчиков событий?

Tags: c#

Возникла необходимость копировать всех обработчиков события ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged в новый объект ObservableCollection.

Я ни разу не копировал список делегатов, скрытый за событием.

Как можно это реализовать? я думаю только через рефлексию, т.к. событие предоставляет только +=   и   -=

Для сортировки объектов ObservableCollection пришлось пересоздавать коллекцию

```
TdsTable = new ObservableCollection<GroupInTds>(TdsTable.OrderBy(gr => gr.Val));
```

но TdsTable событие CollectionChanged  имеет множество подписчиков, которые собирались из разных частей программы и делать переподписку невозможно.

такой код вызывает множественные срабатывания CollectionChanged что тоже не нужно.

```
     var sortCollect = new SortedSet<GroupInTds>(TdsTable);
     TdsTable.Clear();
     TdsTable.AddRange(sortCollect);
```

хотелось бы просто скопировать всех подписчиков.

Comment: Это можно сделать, но зачем это вам? Вы скорее всего что-то делаете не так. Представьте себе, что обработчик события выглядит так: `coll.CollectionChanged += (o, args) => Display(coll)`. Если вы перевесите его на новую коллекцию, обращаться-то он будет всё равно к старой!

Comment: Это уже ошибка дизайна (от криворуких ничто не спасет), правильно должно было быть: coll.CollectionChanged += (o, args) => Display(o) или  coll.CollectionChanged += (o, args) => Display(args) - тогда копирование события не должно иметь артефактов;

Comment: _"копировать всех обработчиков события"_ -- event Action e; ... e.GetInvocationList() - вернет список обработчиков.

Comment: @cpp_user: Ну, тогда нужен каст: `Display((ObservableCollection<T>)o)`. Ну и когда я подписываюсь, я не рассчитываю, что меня кто-то насильно переподпишет — это общепринятая практика.

Comment: @VladD: Что еще за общепринятая практика? Вообще то в событии логика должна быть обобщенной а не прибита гвоздями к владельцу события.

Comment: @cpp_user: Ну, вы же когда пишете функцию, не рассчитываете на то, что во время её вызова объект будет убит из другого потока, например? Каждая функция работает правильно лишь в своих (обычно неявно специфицированных) условиях.

Comment: @VladD: Еще немного и вы начнете пропагандировать здесь глобальные переменные. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, насильная переподписка — это неправильный метод, потому что подписчики наверняка имеют ссылку на старую коллекцию в замыканиях, и будут работать всё так же со старой коллекцией.

Более хороший вариант — просто заменить элементы в `ObservableCollection`. Для того, чтобы не вызывать при этом массово события `OnCollectionChanged`, имеет смысл унаследоваться и определить `AddRange` (код одолжен из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303245/276994)):

```
public class EnhancedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public EnhancedObservableCollection() : base() { }

    public EnhancedObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    public EnhancedObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) { }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        foreach (var item in range)
            Items.Add(item);

        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        this.Items.Clear();
        AddRange(range);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага понял. и в случае использования обычного AddRange вызывать его  из базового класса. СПАСИБО

Comment: @Aldmi: У базового класса (`ObservableCollection<T>`) вообще нет метода `AddRange`. Если у вас он есть, это какой-то самописный extension.

Comment: @Aldmi: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Aldmi: Для вашего случая — да: `TdsTable.Reset(sortCollect);`

Comment: я правильно понял что нужно использовать вот так?
var sortCollect = new SortedSet<GroupInTds>(TdsTable);
TdsTable.Reset(sortCollect);

В таком случае событие дергается
Если закоментирвоать 
this.OnCollectionChanged(
          new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
Тогда не срабаотывает

Comment: @Aldmi: Именно так.